# Stop TinyMCE from applying styles

Tags: 7, wysiwyg

I am building a Drupal 7 boostrap subtheme. I don't want users to be able to add their own fonts and styles to content. I want to force them to use the paragraph and heading tags as defined in my site's CSS.

When users paste in from other sources (eg word) I do not want the styles brought in. Additionally, our site uses Open Sans. This is not appearing in the TinyMCE font list, can this be fixed?

How does one do this with TinyMCE?

Comment: Add style to the tags of the text that TinyMCE generates it

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, but how does one do that?

Comment: I give you my solution as an answer

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with CKEditor. the `h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,p` tags and color picker were available to the user But we wanted every available tag to has a custom color. To do so I put the CKEditor output which was `body` inside a `DIV` with some ID,say `node-body-wrapper`, then added styles like this

```
#node-body-wrapper h1{
     color : red !important;
} 

...
```

In this way I solved the problem. I recommend you to do the same.

Comment: I do not like this answer. It seems an abuse of the !important flag and not optimal CSS. Why can TinyMCE simple be toold NOT to add inline font and font-size styles?

Comment: You can eliminate `!important` and it still works. I usually look for the most straightforward solutions.

Comment: Ok but then my markup is still littered with completely redundant inline styles.

Comment: It is not inline style, inline styles are on html tags!!! Besides that inline styles are not redundant, they have more priority than other styles.

Comment: TinyMCE places style tags in-line, directly on the html output. That is what I am trying to avoid. It is filling my page's html with pointless style tags.

Comment: No these styles are not going to be inline. You must write these styles in a `. css` file. Any way if you find any other or more optimized solution, include it in your question. I will surely use it.

Comment: I think there must be a miscommunication here. My problem is exactly the issue that TinyMCE is adding inline css styles directly to the html that I do not want to the page. I want the <p>, and <h> tags to remain clean and DO NOT want font css in the html tags. Adding overriding CSS in the style sheet is not going to remove the rendered html tags, unless I am missing something. I assume something needs to be done in the wysiwig module or the tinyMCE plugin itself and am looking for some direction in fixing this. Sorry if there is some confusion